# Try to search the forecast of cities with space in the name. Openweathermap API Django Python

Tags: python, django, api, weather, openweathermap

I'm try to resolve the problem of the cities that have space in the name. I look around a bit but i couldn't find anything that match my case.

This is the code:

```
    def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.POST['city']

        source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+ city +'&units=metric&appid=API_KEY').read()

        list_of_data = json.loads(source)
        # print(list_of_data)

        wind_speed = list_of_data['wind']['speed']
        wind_gust =  list_of_data['wind']['gust']



#function for convert the wind speed in knot
        def wind_converter(w,g):
            knots = 2
            kt = (int(w)) + (int(g))* knots
            return kt

        wind_response = wind_converter(wind_speed,wind_gust)

#function for convert deg in cardinal direction

        wind_direction = list_of_data['wind']['deg']

        def degrees_to_cardinal(d):

            dirs = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW']
            ix = round(d / (360. / len(dirs)))
            return dirs[ix % len(dirs)]

        wind_direction = degrees_to_cardinal(wind_direction)

        data = {
            "country_code": str(list_of_data['sys']['country']),
            "coordinate": str(list_of_data['coord']['lon']) + ', '
            + str(list_of_data['coord']['lat']),

            "temp": str(list_of_data['main']['temp']) + ' °C',
            "pressure": str(list_of_data['main']['pressure']),
            "humidity": str(list_of_data['main']['humidity']),
            'main': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['main']),
            'description': str(list_of_data['weather'][0]['description']),
            'icon': list_of_data['weather'][0]['icon'],
            'wind_speed':list_of_data['wind']['speed'],
            'direction':list_of_data['wind']['deg'],
            'wind_gust':list_of_data['wind']['gust'],
            'wind_response':wind_response,
            'wind_direction':wind_direction,
    

        }
        print(data)
    else:
        data = {}
    return render(request, "WindApp/wind_search.html", data)
```

If anyone know how to resolve this problem will be great.
I'd like also understand why the URL can't handle the space in the city name.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [**`urllib.parse.quote_plus`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus):

```
import urllib.parse

city = urllib.parse.quote_plus(request.POST['city'])
```

Answer (score 0):

city = request.POST['city'].replace(' ', '+')

Should do the trick, happy coding